# Service Logins - How to store credentials

Tags: c#, service, authentication, dpapi, credential-manager

In a legacy system (written in `C#` running on `Windows`) services need to use other services. One service is responsible to act upon visitors coming or leaving. The services have to authenticate themselves through a REST API with a user and a password and get a identity token in return. So I need to store the passwords of the services somewhere.
I was looking into Data Protection API (DPAPI), but find that it is [deprecated](https://ax.help.dynamics.com/en/wiki/deprecated-apis/) and I found [software for sale](http://www.passcape.com/index.php?section=docsys&cmd=details&id=28) to crack DPAPI encrypted passwords.
Would you consider using [Credential Manager](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/store-passwords-certificates-and-other-credentials-for-automatic-logon) a good option to use?
Should the passwords in Credential Manager still be encrypted? With what?